# How to display installed app icon in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In jetpack compose, you can display drawables easily with the Image composable like this:

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_drawable))
```

I'm building an app that requires listing all the apps on the device and I need to display their icons. I managed to get the icons using the `PackageManager` class:

```kotlin
val packageManager = context.packageManager
val installedPackages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
val packageInfo = installedPackages[0]
val iconId: Int = packageInfo.applicationInfo.icon
```

Then:

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = iconId))
```

But the app crashes everytime. I don't know where the problem is? Any Idea? Thanks

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of your crash and the code how you work with PackageManager.

Comment: I modified the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `icon` may contain identifier that points to non-existent drawable.

To get application icon use method `loadIcon`:

```kotlin
val icon: Drawable = applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
```

Or method `getApplicationIcon` from PackageManager:

```kotlin
val icon: Drawable = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo)
```

Then, use [AndroidDrawablePainter](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/9a1d64847278876186be81249d9f9eda) to convert Drawable to Painter:

```kotlin
Image(painter = AndroidDrawablePainter(icon))
```

Or [DrawablePainter](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/imageloading-core/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/imageloading/DrawablePainter.kt) is available in [accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/imageloading-core) library:

```kotlin
Image(painter = DrawablePainter(icon))
```

Comment: But `loadIcon()' returns a Drawable and `painterResource()` require the drawable's id

Comment: Add dependency on [accompanist-imageloading-core](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/imageloading-core) or just copy [AndroidDrawablePainter.kt](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/9a1d64847278876186be81249d9f9eda) to your project, and then you can convert Drawable to Painter. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I added the `accompanist` library dependency to my project but I get `Unresolved reference: AndroidDrawablePainter`. And thank you

Comment: Try DrawablePainter instead of AndroidDrawablePainter

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Coil library](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/), `rememberImagePainter` will accept an `Any?` as its `data` argument, allowing you to use the `Drawable` returned from the `PackageManager`, like so:

```
  Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
      data = LocalContext.current.packageManager.getApplicationIcon("com.package.example")
    )
  )
```