# How to get icons of installed apps?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

There are a lot of Java sample codes, but I couldn't find any results for Jetpack Compose. 
I have a ViewModel and it returns a list of package names. I want to show the application icons.

A [similar problem has occurred before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68330199/how-to-display-installed-app-icon-in-jetpack-compose), but coudn't find a solution from the answers.

```
class MalwareListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val malwareList = mutableListOf<String>()
    fun getMalwareList(): List<String> {
        return malwareList
    }
}
```

Comment: "cannot find a solution for the answers" -- then please edit your question with a [mcve] that shows what you tried, and explain *in detail* what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a `ApplicationInfo` object from an app package name using [`getApplicationInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) and then use that to load the app icon:

```
val malwareIcons = mutableListOf<Drawable>()
for (packageName in malwareList) {
    try {
        val appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);  // may throw NameNotFoundException
        val appIcon: Drawable = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo)
        malwareIcons.add(appIcon)
    } catch(NameNotFoundException n) {
        Log.e("MalwareViewModel", "Package Name $packageName not found.")
    }
}
```

The list `malwareIcons` then contains all icons of the package names in your `malwareList`.